# Laravel : Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$id

Tags: php, laravel

Dear fellow programmers,

I have encountered an issue on my project, The problem is that i was unable to retrieve data from MYSQL Database.

I followed the tutorial step by step,  and im sure my code was right.

Heres my web.php

```
Route::get('viewprofile','pagecontroller@view');
Route::get('/viewprofile','Controller@getProfile');
```

Heres my controller getProfile function
function getProfile()

```
  {
        $users['users'] = DB::table('users')->get();

        if(count($users) > 0)
        {
            return view('viewprofile',$users);
        }
        else
        {
                return view('viewprofile');
        }
    }
```

Heres my viewprofile.blade.php

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>ID : </td>
            <td>Username : </td>
            <td>Email : </td>
        </tr>
         @foreach($users as $value)
         <tr>
            <td>{{  $users->id }}</td>
            <td>{{  $users->name }}</td>
            <td>{{  $users->email }}</td>
        </tr>
            @endforeach
    </table>
```

My database is called finalprojectSL, and my table was named users, with attributes :

```
id
name
email
password
retypepassword
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you, 
Best Regards

Comment: Did you not get an undefined variable error? Based on your getProfile code there should be no variable named `$users` in the scope of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace it by this:

```
$value->id
$value->name
$value->email
```

Comment: it's now undefined variable : users

Comment: Your method doesnt work sir, but i got a brief inspiration from that. and now it worked xD .. Thank you so much

Comment: you changed it to @foreach($users['users'] as $value) ? :) welcome

Answer (score 0):

In here

```
if(count($users) > 0)
{
    return view('viewprofile',$users);
}
```

Instead do

```
if (count($users) > 0) 
{
    return view('viewprofile', compact('users'));
}
```

And change your blade to

```
@foreach($users['users'] as $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{{  $value->id }}</td>
        <td>{{  $value->name }}</td>
        <td>{{  $value->email }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Previously you were trying to do `$users->id`. `$users` is a `collection` and id doesn't contain an `id` hence `Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$id`

Answer (score 0):

The 'model' User needs to have the ID on `$fillable` variable;

In your User Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    ... others fields
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code need to update like :

### function getProfile()

```
public function getProfile()
{
$users = DB::table('users')->get();


 if(count($users) > 0)
 {

     return view('viewprofile',compact('users'));
 }
 else
 {
         return view('viewprofile');
 }

}
```

### viewprofile.blade.php

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>ID : </td>
   <td>Username : </td>
   <td>Email : </td>
 </tr>
 @if(isset($users))
   @foreach($users as $value)
     <tr>
       <td>{{  $value->id }}</td>
       <td>{{  $value->name }}</td>
       <td>{{  $value->email }}</td>
     </tr>
   @endforeach
 @endif
</table>
```

Hope this work for you!